# How to find out which server has less hops between user or specific IP?

Tags: voip

Lets assume I have a VoIP service on several servers in different location and I have clients all over world.
When client make request I should be able to reply back to my client which server to use for RTP which will use a lot of data. I believe I can do this simply by checking user IP. Probably I should choice server which have less hops between itself and client, but off cause it do not guarantee best speed or lowest delay.

Is there any API for this or how is possible to achieve this? I will not consider ping or trace-route for this.

Thank you!

Comment: Why would you avoid using the tools made specifically for that (ping and traceroute)?  Considering the number of open source traceroute solutions, copying one's logic to do the task seems like the simplest option.  What language do you want to use?

Comment: It might work for 1 or 2 client, but I f I have 10 000 clients, I don't want to DDOS my server and all network equipment between client and server.

I was thinking that there might be some kind of API where I can feed IPs and it will reply with best route...

Comment: That comment means that you have some learning to do on routing which is **dynamic**.  There are ip geolocation solutions which could point you in the right direction, but they can't reliably show which server is closer in terms of networking.  Last week I was analyzing a case of a server in the US for which the traffic from most of North America was routed to the UK before coming back and reaching its destination.  Only a ping could make that apparent.

Comment: Note that you can no accidentally DDOS a machine, even if you send it 1000 pings in one shot.

Comment: You are wrong, regarding ping ddos
http://ghostgrid.blog.com/2010/12/16/ping-flooding/

Answer (score 0):

You can just send an echo request from clients to all your servers and use the server from where the first answer was received. This can be a simple UDP packet and you need to make this only at first launch and remember the answer.